# Opening winscp in the same folder as opened putty session

Tags: linux, putty, winscp

Say I am in /home/user/folder1/folder2/ in putty i want to open winscp in that folder.I can do the other way around; Open putty in current folder from winscp.Or atleast is there any other software that manages both ssh and sftp both and can provide me with this functionality(open ssh in current folder when in sftp session, open ssh in current folder when in ssh session).

Comment: You should take a look at "bitwise",

Answer (score 1):

kitty has this feature: https://www.9bis.net/kitty/#!pages/PscpIntegration.md

You have to create this bash function:

```
winscp() { echo -ne "\033];__ws:${PWD}\007"; }
```

Then you can open winscp from the command line.

Answer (score -1):

MobaXterm has the feature to set sftp window follow the folder structure of ssh terminal